# Jenkins Configuration with "none" credentials

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am new to Jenkins setup.

I am observing a strange behavior while setting up a new job with a "FreeStyle project" with "**none**" credentials.

Ideally, with none credentials, the Jenkins should throw an error, while authenticating thebitbucket url. However, surprisingly it got authenticated (at the time of configuring the job). Later when I ran the job (with "**none**" credentials) it also cloned the repository contents in my workspace folder and the job turned out to be successful.

I dont understand the following:
=> what's the use of creating a new "Jenkins" credentials, when "none" itself brings down the code?
=> what's the use of creating an "App Password" in Bitbucket?

I want that:
=> the Jenkins **should throw authentication error** while connecting the bitbucket url when I specify "**none**" in the "credentials" section
=> the Jenkins **should successfully authenticate **the bitbucket url when I specify / select a valid "Jenkins" user

[Image :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shexv.png)

Answer (score 0):

its normal behaviour, it means "you dont use any credentials" its java none object, mock value, its expected

if your repo is public you dont need any credentials to clone/checkout repo

in your case: any public project will not be possible to use

```
/**
    * Adds an "empty" credential to signify selection of no credential.
    *
    * @return {@code this} for method chaining.
    * @since 2.1.0
*/
@NonNull
public AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel<T, C> includeEmptyValue() {
    for (Option a : this) {
        if (StringUtils.equals("", a.value)) {
            return this;
        }
    }
    add(0, new Option(Messages.AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel_EmptySelection(), ""));
    return this;
}
```

[code1](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/54b1c2c6388a3eaf49d3bd4ab55ab15b2abc2482/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/common/AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel.java#L164-L179)

[code2](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/common/Messages.properties#L24)

creadentials needed when you need to connect to private repo, or extend token permissions/assess to that repo

so this user can potentially do force push for example

Comment: Hello Ruslan, but mine is a private repo. When logging into bitbucket i cant access the repo without specifying credentials

Comment: see https://medium.com/@nitingupta.bciit/jenkins-automated-build-with-private-bitbucket-repository-51964ad3d53a

you have to have any auth to private repo, ssh or creds